# Rails model fails format validation, regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, model, rspec, tdd

I'm setting up a model for recordings with the following constraints

```
class Recording < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :agent_id, :confirmation, :filepath, :phone, :call_queue_id, :date
  belongs_to :call_queue

  PHONE_FORMAT = /^[0-9]+$|Unavailable/

  validates_presence_of :call_queue_id, :agent_id, :phone, :filepath, :date
  validates :phone, format: { with: PHONE_FORMAT }
end
```

and am trying to test it with the following spec

```
describe Recording do
  let(:queue) { FactoryGirl.create(:call_queue) }
  before { @recording = queue.recordings.build(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:recording)) }
  subject { @recording }

  # Stuff omitted...

  describe "phone" do
    it "should be present" do
      @recording.phone = ''
      @recording.should_not be_valid
    end

    context "with a valid format" do
      it "should only consist of digits" do
        @recording.phone = 'ab4k5s'
        @recording.should_not be_valid
      end

      it "should only match 'Unavailable'" do
        @recording.phone = 'Unavailable'
        @recording.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end  
end
```

The first two tests pass, but the third fails with the following:

```
Failure/Error: @recording.should be_valid
   expected valid? to return true, got false
```

I tested my regex with [rubular](http://rubular.com) to make sure it was working, and then again using irb just to be sure. I'm really confused why this is failing.

EDIT:

I eventually got the specs to pass by changing my `before` statement in the rspec:

```
describe Recording do
  let(:queue) { FactoryGirl.create(:call_queue) }
  before(:each) { @recording = queue.recordings.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:recording) }
  # the rest is the same...
```

which ultimately makes sense to me, to a point. Was the reason everything was getting messed up (falses were returning true, and vice versa) because once an attribute made the record invalid, I couldn't change it again? It seems like that was the case, I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
PHONE_FORMAT = /^([0-9]+|Unavailable)$/
```

Comment: With no forward slashes? Do I need quotes of any kind?

Comment: I added that with forward slashes and got the same error as before

Comment: @BradRice Yeh that was a typo, should of been slashes (fixed). I don't seem to be able to replicate the error your getting though...